# How to stop VS code from always searching occurences of words not in selection?

Tags: visual-studio-code

i find really annoying the fact that VS code always try to search occurences of words that aren't even in selection.

personally i don't like the fact that every time i rest my cursor something all the occurences are highlighted.

i know that VS code is really customizable, so is there a way to change this behavior ?

here's a gif illustrating my question
left is VS code, right is Sublime text 3.
we can clearly see that sublime only search for occurence that are selected

Thanks a lot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

here we go.

this option in settings will do the job